# should I use custom spring-boot-starter for sharing @Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have several projects that all need the same controller.  It seems like putting the controller into the starter I'm working on the would make reusing this controller easy.  However, I'm concerned that starter's are really mean for configuration and not something like controllers.

Any opinions on if it is already to share a controller via a custom starter project?  For the record this does work, but in my spring boot app I have to @Import(MyController.class).

If its not already what would be the best way to share a controller like this?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?